# Cesaro means and Banach limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, fa.functional-analysis

Consider the class of bounded sequences to which every Banach limit (non-negative shift-invariant continuous functional on $l^\infty$ taking convergent sequences in the usual sense to their limits) assigns the same limit value.

**Does a sequence belong to this class if its Cesaro means have a limit?**

Also, is the converse true?

Comment: I like the question, but  I would like to make sure I understand correctly the notion of Banach limit.   From your formulation I understand that a Banach limit is a linear map $L:\ell^infty(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ with the property that $L(\;(x_n)_{n\geq 0}\;)=L(\;(y_n)_{n\geq 0}\;) $  if  $x_n=y_n$ for all $n$ sufficiently large. Is the  functional $L$ continuous in the $\ell^\infty$ topology?

Comment: If $L$ is a Banach limit, then $|Lx|\le\|x\|_\infty$ for any sequence $x$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thanks.  $L$ is therefore an element of the topological dual of $\ell^\infty$.

Comment: Sequences with this property are called [almost convergent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_convergent_sequence) and there exists a well-known characterization of such sequences due to Lorenz; which is described in the Wikipedia article. One possibility how to show this is using Hahn-Banach theorem, see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/80571/8297) at Math.SE. Also the references from the Wikipedia article might be useful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can characterize Banach limits as continuous functionals on $\ell^\infty$ which vanish on
$$ X := \{(x_n - x_{n+1}): (x_n) \in \ell^\infty\} $$
and which send the constant sequence $(1,1,\dots)$ to $1$.

Note that $X$ is a subspace.
The Hahn-Banach Theorem tells us that we are asking: if $(y_n) \in \ell^\infty$ has Cesaro mean $0$, is it in the closure of $X$?
(And the converse question is: does every element of $X$ have Cesaro mean $0$?
Yes; since the $n^\text{th}$ Cesaro mean of $(x_n-x_{n+1})$ is $(x_1-x_{n+1})/n$, which converges to $0$ since $(x_n)$ is uniformly bounded.)

The answer is no.
Consider the sequence $(y_n)$ that has $1$ once, followed by $-1$ three times, then $1$ five times, and so on.
One can compute the Cesaro mean, and see that it approaches $0$ in the limit.
But $(y_n)$ is not in the closure of $X$.

Surely, if it were, then let $(x_n) \in \ell^\infty$ be such that 
$$ \|(y_n) - (x_n-x_{n+1})\|_\infty < 1/2. $$
Let $M$ be a natural number, $M \geq \|(x_n)\|$. 
Let $n$ be an index such that 
$$ y_n = \cdots = y_{n+4M} = 1. $$ 
Then for $i=1,\dots,4M$,
$$ x_{n+i} < x_{n + i-1} - y_{n + i - 1} + 1/2 = x_{n + i - 1} - 1/2, $$
and summing these up, we find
$$ x_{n+4M} < x_n - 4M/2. $$
This contradicts the assumption that $\|(x_n)\| \leq M$.

Comment: Is there a typo in the second equation from the bottom? In the middle expression you write $x+y$, where must be $x-y$. (I believe the idea does work anyway!) Also, it is not quite obvious why every element of $X$ has Cesaro mean 0.

Comment: Thank you, I think that it is all correct now.  I have added a bit of explanation about why the elements of $X$ have Cesaro mean zero.

Comment:    Nice answer!  By the way? Is there a constructive example of Banach limit functional?


Comment: @Liviu: I believe there isn't.  See mathoverflow.net/questions/5351/whats-an-example-of-a-space-that-needs-the-hahn-banach-theorem/5366

Answer (score 4):

If $(x_n) \in \ell^\infty$. According to Lorenz the Banch limit is unique (also known as *almost convergent*) iff
$$\lim_{p\mapsto\infty} \frac{ x_n + x_{n+1} + \cdots + x_{n+p}}{p} = L  \quad (*) $$
uniformly in $n$. Setting $n=0$ yields Cesaro summability.

As Aaron says, the converse is false. If each $x_n$ is chosen uniformly at random from $\{0,1\}$ then this sequence almost never has property $(*)$ (see Connor's appropriately named article *Almost none of the sequences of 0's and 1's are almost convergent*)

However the Cesaro limit of this random sequence $(x_n)$ is almost always $1/2$ by the law of large numbers.